# Selecting each input fields in the table column with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the input fields' values in each column.

```
<table id="tablo">
     <tr>
         <td><input class="Name" type="text" /></td>
         <td><input class="Age" type="text" /></td>
         <td><input class="No" type="text" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input class="Name" type="text" /></td>
         <td><input class="Age" type="text" /></td>
         <td><input class="No" type="text" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input class="Name" type="text" /></td>
         <td><input class="Age" type="text" /></td>
         <td><input class="No" type="text" /></td>
     </tr>
     ...
</table>
```

Then selecting each input value, I will create an object with these values and push the object in an array by looping through the selected inputs:

```
var arr= []
var obj = {
    Name: jquery selector will come here,
    Age: jquery selector will come here,
    No: jquery selector will come here
}
arr.push(obj);
```

I've tried with jQuery's $.each() function, but I just only reach the columns.

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__, Your HTML is invalid. First correct it

Comment: So loop over and build the objects.

Comment: A simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuhsy2vy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id must be unique, so try it with using class like,

```
var objs=[];
$('#tablo tr').each(function(){
  var inputs = $(this).find('input'),o={};
  inputs.each(function(){
     o[$(this).attr('class')]=this.value;
  });
  objs.push(o);
});
```

**Snippet,**

```js
var objs = [];
$('#tablo tr').each(function() {
  var inputs = $(this).find('input'), o = {};
  inputs.each(function() {
    o[$(this).attr('class')] = this.value;
  });
  objs.push(o);
});
console.log(objs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablo">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="Name" type="text" value="test1"/></td>
    <td><input class="Age" type="text" value="123"/></td>
    <td><input class="No" type="text" value="no1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="Name" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="Age" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="No" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="Name" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="Age" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="No" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I check the null input values?

Comment: I've edited the code you sent to check the input values, but didn't work.

var objs = [];
$('#tablo tr').each(function() {
    var inputs = $(this).find('input'), o = {};
    inputs.each(function() {
        o[$(this).attr('class')] = this.value;
    });
    if(o['Name'] =! undefined && o['Yas'] =! undefined && o['No'] =! undefined)
    {
        ogrenciler.push(o);
    }
    objs.push(o);
});

Comment: Use `!=` instead of `=!` and `o['Age']` in place of `o['Yas']`

Comment: I've fixed it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nuhsy2vy/1/), but didn't work again. It pushed the first row's input values but didn't push the others row's input values which either isn't undefined or undefined.

Comment: Try to use  `if(o['Name'] && o['Age'] && o['No'])` condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this: you can iterate earch row first and then read each input.
Note: id must be unique throughout the DOM, hence replaced with classes

```js
$(function(){
  var array = [];
  $('#tablo tr').each(function(){
     var obj = {};
     //obj['name']=$(this).find('td input:eq(0)').val();
     //obj['age']=$(this).find('td input:eq(1)').val();
     //obj['no']=$(this).find('td input:eq(2)').val();

     //for dynamic build of object
     $(this).find('input').each(function(){
         obj[$(this).attr('class')]=$(this).val();
      });
     array.push(obj);
  });
  
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablo">
     <tr>
         <td><input class="Name" type="text" value="name1"/></td>
         <td><input class="Age" type="text" value="name1"/></td>
         <td><input class="No" type="text" value="name1"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input class="Name" type="text" value="name2"/></td>
         <td><input class="Age" type="text" value="age2"/></td>
         <td><input class="No" type="text" value="no2"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><input class="Name" type="text" value="name3"/></td>
         <td><input class="Age" type="text" value="age3"/></td>
         <td><input class="No" type="text" value="no3"/></td>
     </tr>
     ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace input id's with classes of the same name.
Then loop over rows like this:

```
var arr = [];
$('#table tr').each(function(tr, index) {
  var name = $(tr).find('.Name').val()
  var age = $(tr).find('.Age').val()
  var no = $(tr).find('.No').val()
  arr.push({name:name, age:age, no:no});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the issue with the ids before (ids should be unique in the document)
then with jquery will be as easy as:

```
const inputs = $('#tablo').find('input');
```

You even don't need jquery

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#tablo input');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **dots** in **find** for read ALL imputs, Like if work for u

```
$('#bodyt tr').each(function(){
            var inputs = $(this).find(':input'), row={};
            inputs.each(function(){
              row[$(this).attr('idm')]  = this.value;
            });
            ob.solicitud.push(row);
          });
```